# Why aren't the Subversive plugin options appearing in my Eclipse projects?

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins, subversive, eclipse-mars

I’m using the following version of Eclipse on Mac 10.9.5 (actually SpringSource Tool Suite):

```
Version: 3.7.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201506290652
Platform: Eclipse Mars (4.5.0)
```

I’m trying to install the Subversive plugin for use with my Maven projects (using SVN).  I downloaded the zip file from their website,  Then i created the following directory:

```
/Applications/STS.app/Contents/Eclipse/dropins/SubVersive/
```

I unzipped the plugin into this directory.  Then I restarted my Eclipse instance.  However, upon right clicking on my projects from the Package Explorer, I do not see any options for checkin under “Team”.  On a command line, these projects do have “.svn” directories and I can use SVN fine on the command line.  What else do I need to do to get Subversive to install?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you follow this instructions?
https://eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php

Comment: Because no Subversive checkboxes appear when I do the step "Expand the Collaboration group and select the Subversive features ".

Comment: Try to use the "Option 3 - Use Eclipse Marketplace Client" in phase 1.

Comment: I tried this, insatlling from teh Marketplace, restarted my Eclipse instance when told the installation was complete, but still when I right click on my projects from teh package explorer, there are no check in options under "Team".

Comment: Have you installed svn connectors? You can check it at Preferences > Team > SVN > SVN Connector tab.